# Хранение паролей в Python

Tags: python, безопасность

Как в python реализовать безопасное хранение и использование паролей?
Т.е. нужно считать от пользователя введенный пароль, в зашифрованном виде сохранить в конфигурационном файле, а затем по необходимости считывать, расшифровать и использовать в скрипте и для авторизации на внешнем сервисе.

Comment: А от кого обезопасить хотите? Ключ-то для расшифровки пароля будет в скрипте и доступ к файлу с паролем наверняка будет означать и доступ к скрипту.

Answer (score 4):

От используемого языка безопасное хранение не зависит. Раз пароль нужен для авторизации на внешнем сервисе и этот внешний сервис не предусматривает какого нибудь API с временными токенами, то хранить придется в расшифровывамом виде. А это в любом случае не безопасно. Как только кто то добирается до скрипта, видит алгоритм, видит ключ шифрования - все, он знает все пароли.

Если нужно просто скрыть от посторонних глаз, то подойдет даже не особо сложное шифрование, хоть наложением XOR постоянного ключа, можно предварительно сжать любым алгоритмом сжатия, а после шифровки, если конфиг текстовый - обработать base64.

Если вопрос безопасности действительно критичен и невозможно организовать запрос пароля у пользователя каждый раз, то для всех скриптов оперирующих с открытыми паролями должен быть выделен отдельный сервер, на котором не будет никаких посторонних сервисов. Фаерволом должны быть закрыты все порты, кроме необходимых для работы сервисов и доступа персонала. Доступ персонала должен быть минимизирован, ограничен на уровне фаервола только с определенных ip + стандартные или ужесточенные средства аутентификации. На сервере должен быть сервис (бакэнд) который принимает пароли от другой машины, которая их получает от пользователей. скрипт должен быть выверен и заведомо не содержать ошибок, никакой работы помимо сохранения паролей и приема команд на выполнение работы с использованием этих паролей он вести не должен. 
Если возможно, он должен работать самостоятельно, без поддержки web-сервера, просто принимать конкретные команды от фронтэнда по собственному протоколу. Весь трафик разумеется должен шифроваться SSL. Бакэнд должен убеждаться в правильности сертификата посылающей данные стороны до начала выполнения каких либо других действий.
Если предполагается выполнение работы с использованием паролей по запросам извне - то это самый проблемный участок, потому как злоумышленник, попав на сервер который отдает команды может начать отдавать свои, ему тогда даже сами пароли и доступ на машину с паролями не понадобятся. Кроме того, если злоумышленник попадает на систему, которая ведет первичный сбор паролей у пользователей, внедрит в систему свой скрипт, который будет сохранять пароли и пересылать злоумышленнику.

Из всего этого вывод один - безопасное хранение обратимо зашифрованных паролей не возможен в принципе. Так что вопрос только в критичности потенциальной утечки данных.

Comment: опция №1, которую с большим акцентом следует упомянуть: делегировать вопрос идентификации пользователей третьему ресурсу (Google, ВКонтакте -- как на текущем сайте) и соответственно *не хранить пароли*. Опция №2: часть секрета хранить на клиенте и/или голове пользователя (master-password) и соответственно серверы не имеют информации, чтобы расшифровать пароли сами по себе. Если всё-таки надо пароль (или лучше временный per-app access token) хранить, то посмотреть, предоставляет ли сервис что-то вроде facebook's `appsecret_proof`, чтобы ограничить использование токена.